# show/hide - the form will not close even after clicking the submit, unless user click the hide

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<button id="hidr">Hide</button>
<button id="showr">Show</button>
<div>
<span style='display:none'>

<?php
    <form id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action='do.php?sales/new_stat_rep'>
        <table  class='generic'>

        <tr bgcolor='13a0ff'><td colspan='6'><center><b>CREATE STATUS REPORT</b></center></td></tr>
            <tr bgcolor='4ab6ff'>
                <td>J.O. Date</td><td><input type='text' name='sm_jodate' value='MM/DD/YYYY' onfocus='showCalendarControl(this)' style='width:100%'></td>
                <td>Proposal Number</td><td><input type='text' name='sm_proposalno' style='width:100%'></td>
                <td>Project Duration</td><td><input name='sm_proj_duration' type='text' style='width:100%'></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
            <input type='submit' value='Save' name='sumbit'>
            <input type='hidden' name='button' value='yes'>
    </form>

?>

    </span>

  </div>

<script>
    $("#showr").click(function () {
      $("span").show(1000);
    });
    $("#hidr").click(function () {
      $("span:last-child").hide("fast", function () {
        // use callee so don't have to name the function
        $(this).prev().hide("fast", arguments.callee); 
      });
    });


</script>
```

---

This code has a 2 button at first the hide and show.. in order to view the form the user must click the show. My concern, if is possible when i submit the inputs in form the form will not close, unless the user click the hide. button, and how to do that

Comment: Your code seems to be doing that already. Do you mean you want to send the data without refreshing the page? (Thus, not hiding the form again) If so, you should look into AJAX.

Comment: yeah? i just want the encoder not clicking the show when he/she need to encode a loots of data, he/she need to click it once and click hide when the user is done

Comment: why did u use <?php ?> in this code?

Comment: Is this page `do.php`? In other words does it submit to itself?

Comment: Yeah, it won't hide the form automatically. You would need to bind the hiding code to the submit button to make it hide automatically.

Comment: @ Mangala Edirisinghe actually the code inside the form is not complete is has a lot of code, i just put i think 1 to 3? text box, for sample only, it has a <?php ?> couz in the middle of original code it has some echo "$abcde"; like that

Comment: @MrCode the do.php contains all of my function.. at the end of the fuction it has a goback(); in order to back in that code(above ^)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type='submit' value='Save' name='sumbit' id="SubmitFrm">
```

add below code in your script

```
$("#SubmitFrm").click(function(){
     $("#hidr").click();
});
```

Comment: what does your goback(); method do ?

Comment: is it just like javascript history go back ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#showr").click(function () {
  $("span").show(1000);
});
$("#hidr").click(function () {
  $("span:last-child").hide("fast", function () {
    // use callee so don't have to name the function
    $(this).prev().hide("fast", arguments.callee); 
  });
});
$("#submit").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#form1").submit();
});
```

try this. it is working. add id to your submit button(id="submit" in my code).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mangalauwu/kh9Vm/1/)

Comment: i try ur code sir yeah it is correct but the problem is, when i click save the record that i put in my form did not save to my database and when i click save the previous input stay,

Comment: jquery submit also same as normal form submission. check your submit page and echo those value on that page. may be problem with it.